# How to change the title of Timepicker and localization in custom renderer

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I have Xamarin forms time picker following custom renderer for IOS

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(TimePicker), typeof(Time24PickerRenderer))]
namespace LabOraTimeStamp.iOS.Renderers
{
    public class Time24PickerRenderer:TimePickerRenderer
    {
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<TimePicker> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            var timePicker = (UIDatePicker)Control.InputView;
            timePicker.Locale = new NSLocale("no_nb");

            //Get the Done button
            var toolbar = (UIToolbar)Control.InputAccessoryView;
            var doneBtn = toolbar.Items[1];

            //Set the Done to OK
            doneBtn.Title = "OK";
        }
    }
}
```

I wanted to change the default "done" to "Ok".

1) How can I do that? the line mentioned above for setting the title does not affect anything.

2) I already implemented localization for xamarin forms.I just wanted to use existing Resx values from custom renderer to show the string for appropriate culture.How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the reason why your code isn't working is because the done button is created with the UIBarButtonSystemItem.Done style. It doesn't care about the Title property. [Renderer code here.](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS/Renderers/TimePickerRenderer.cs)

To work around that issue you could try replacing the Xamarin created done button with your own custom Ok button.

```
//Get the Done button
var toolbar = (UIToolbar)Control.InputAccessoryView;

// Replace Xamarin's buttons with custom ones.
var spacer = new UIBarButtonItem(UIBarButtonSystemItem.FlexibleSpace);
var doneButton = new UIBarButtonItem();
doneButton.Title = "OK";
doneButton.Clicked += (o, a) => Control.ResignFirstResponder();
toolbar.SetItems(new [] { spacer, doneButton}, false);
```

Comment: Thank you .It does the work.Yes as you said the Title property does nothing while the style is applied.